# DisposableObserver<> is not subtype of Observer<>

Tags: kotlin, rx-android

I am trying to convert [this RxJava/RxAndroid lesson](https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/android-getting-started-with-reactive-programming/#example5) to RxKotlin/RxAndroid.
At the method at Example5 I get error from picture

[image: error]

My getNotesObservable() function is:

```
fun getNotesObservable(): Observable<Note>{
    val notes: List<Note> = prepareNotes()
    return Observable.create {
        for (note in notes) {
            if (!it.isDisposed){ // onNext only if observable is not disposed
                it.onNext(note)
            }
        }

        if (!it.isDisposed) {
            it.onComplete()
        }
    }
}
```

and part with error is:

```
disposable.add(
        getNotesObservable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map{
                it.note = it.note.toUpperCase()
            }
            .subscribeWith(getNotesObserver())
    )
```

So, what's should I change in my code?

Comment: The return type deduced for the `map` call is `Observable<in Unit!>`. Try to return `it` in the `map` function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that I needed was return statement (from picture below)
Thanks for [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53514768/8230881)

[image]