# mapping custom data RxAndroid with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I am trying to convert examples from [this article](https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/android-getting-started-with-reactive-programming/#example5) from Java to Kotlin.
I get error from picture at Exmaple 5:

[image]

And I noticed, that without map() function I don't get this error

[image]

So, what the point of this error and how to write it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of a lambda in Kotlin is always the last expression in the block.

So in this case the result of

```
.map { it.note = it.note.toUpperCase() }
```

is not returning a meaningful value.

What you should do instead is this

```
.map { 
    it.note = it.note.toUpperCase()
    it
}
```

Which returns a type of Note instead of Unit.